# Simplify std::string construction involving concatenating integers in C++

Tags: c++, string, integer, concatenation

Looking for a more elegant shortcut to the following:

```
for (int i=1; i<=maxNum; i++)
{
   std::ostringstream s;
   s << i;
   std::string group1 = "group1_" + s.str();
   std::string group2 = "group2_" + s.str();
   .
   .
   .

   val = conf->read(group1.c_str());
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Can anyone think of an elegant way like:

```
conf->read({SOMEMACRO or function}("group1_", i));
```

Can this be done in place with a built-in C++ facility?  Btw, boost is not an option.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the input, and what should be the end result?

Comment: What, exactly, is not elegant in this code?  So far, the answers proposed have slower speed, threading issues or risk buffer overruns.  It seems to me the current solution is elegant.

Comment: It's actually quite nasty having to using ostringstream just to concatenate string and ints.  Plus, I'm constructing like 15 different strings as local variables.  Wish string and int concatenation was supported in C++ like in Java, etc..

Comment: @chrikirk: you mean a type-safe `sprintf()`-like format operation?  A lot of people would like it, that's why it's part of boost.  I hope it makes it into the standard library, though.

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like:

```
inline std::string construct_group_id(int n, int i)
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << "group" << n << "_" << i;
    return s.str();
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't scale up. What the OP basically needs is a convenient, terse lexical cast.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd use a (somewhat restricted) copy of Boost's lexical_cast:

```
template <class T, class U>
T lexical_cast(U const &input) { 
     std::stringstream buffer;
     buffer << input;

     T ret;
     buffer >> ret;
     return ret;
}

for (int i=0; i<maxNum; i++)
    val = conf->read("group1_" + lexical_cast<std::string>(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a static wrapper around `itoa`.  It is not thread-safe.

```
static const char * static_itoa( const int val )
{
    static char buff[20];
    return itoa( val, buff, 10 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little helper function to do the trick:

```
inline std::string myitoa(size_t n)
{
  std::string res = n ? "" : "0";
  while(n) { res += '0' + (n % 10); n /= 10; }
  return std::string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{ 
  const std::string n = myitoa(i+1);

  std::string g1 = "group1_" + n;
  /* ... */
}
```

This requires your encoding to store the numeral characters contiguously and N less than 10.