# C++ Automatically inserting int value within " " marks

Tags: c++, file

My program requires the user to input an int value. I need the application to insert the inputted int value within " " marks, which makes it a string value, thus enabling me to save a txt file with the string value.

example:

user inputs int: 123
Program adds quotation marks: "123"
so new string has the value: "123"

I can now use the new string value to save a file with that string as the file name.

Without quotation marks ifstream doesn't allow me to save a file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show us *relevant* parts of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote marks here are pretty much a red herring. They're neither necessary nor sufficient for what you're trying to accomplish.

You have a couple of choices. One would be to read the user's input as a string instead of an arithmetic type:

```
std::string fname;

std::cout << "Please enter integer for file name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, fname);

std::fstream file(fname);
```

Another would be to enter the number as an integer, but then convert that to a string:

```
int fnum;

std::cin >> fnum;

std::string fname = std::to_string(fnum);

std::fstream f(fname);
```

Chances are pretty good you'll want to add a file extension, so if the user enters `123`, your filename ends up as (say) `123.txt`. To do that, you could do something like: `fname += ".txt";` just before you create the fstream object.

Edit:

Here's a complete/compilable demo, tested with VC++ 2012:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    int fnum;

    std::cout << "Please enter integer for file name: ";
    std::cin >> fnum;

    std::string fname = std::to_string(fnum);

    fname += ".txt";
    std::ofstream f(fname);
    f << "Contents";
}
```

Running this and entering (for example) `123`, I get a file named `123.txt` containing "Contents".

Roughly similar code works with g++ 4.7.2 as well, but (at least the copy I have) doesn't include `std::to_string` yet, so that part needs trivial rewriting to work with it.

Comment: This is the case: I open a new txt file with -> ofstream myfile; myfile.open ("file_name"); But I want the file to be saved with whatever the INT value the user enters. So for that, I need the int to be within quotation marks.. or else an error occurs

Comment: @PJ_Boy: You probably need to show us the code and the error. I've created files name things like `1.txt` without any problem using code like I've shown above.

Comment: @PJ_Boy No, you don't need anything between quotation marks. This is an XY problem.

Comment: How do you save a file using whatever int the user enters? @Jerry Coffin thats exactly what I want, saving a file with the int user enters. I use myfile.open ("file_name"); method to do this.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I want, sir. Could you please give me the code that saves the file with the int value user enters + the txt extension?

Comment: @PJ_Boy: You do it like the code in my answer shows. Oh, one minor detail: if you're using an older compiler, you may need to use something like `std::fstream f(fname.c_str())` instead. Taking a string was added in C++11, so older compilers don't allow it.

Comment: Brilliant code work, Thank you good sir but I do get a minor error: `to_string' is not a member of `std'. I'm new to C++. kinda dont know how to trouble shoot this :)

Comment: @PJ_Boy: since `to_string` was added to C++ fairly recently, some compilers don't have it yet. You could use `lexical_cast<std::string>` instead (e.g., lexical_cast shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6496104/179910)).

Comment: @PJ_Boy `std::to_string` requires C++11 (the latest standardized version of C++). You could either use an alternative, or (IMO the better option, if you can), either upgrade your compiler (all the major toolchains support C++11, IIRC), or enable C++11 support in the compiler (some require explicitly requesting C++11 mode).

Comment: Thanks for your time, This would be the answer. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do that. You can save the "number" to a string directly:

```
// read input
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

// open output file with input as name
std::ofstream output_file(input.c_str()); // c_str() not needed in C++11
```

Of course, you should have some intermediate step to do some input validation.

Comment: String is not the problem, I need it inside quotation marks. Adding quotation marks is my main objective. So when I save the file, it can save it as the int value (which is inside the "" marks)

Comment: @PJ_Boy what you are saying makes absolutely no sense. I think you should clarify your question.

Comment: @juanchopanza c++11 is there a conversion operator char*?

Comment: @Koushik No, but there is an additional constructor that takes `const std::string&`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream).